# navigation property on a view

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

I got following situation. I have `Deliverers` and `Promotions` tables linked with `DelivererId` on `Promotions` (foreign key). In my MVC app I simply display list of promotions with this code:

```
                    promotions = db.Promotions.
                    Include("Deliverers1").
                    Where(p => p.WeekNo == currentWeek).
                    OrderByDescending(p => p.WeekNo);
```

I was asked to add another column which is dynamically computed (select count(*) on another table). My solution was to create a view as `select *, count(....) from Promotions ...`.

The problem is that my view does not have Deliverers1 navigation property and I have no idea how to add it. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If another table is a property navigation of this entity:

```
var promotions = db.Promotions.
                    Include("Deliverers1").
                    Where(p => p.WeekNo == currentWeek).
                    OrderByDescending(p => p.WeekNo)
                    .Select(p=>new {p,p.Count(...));
```

If not a property navigation:

```
var promotions = db.Promotions.
                    Include("Deliverers1").
                    Where(p => p.WeekNo == currentWeek).
                    OrderByDescending(p => p.WeekNo)
                    .Select(p=>new {p,db.othertable.Where(q=>q.foo==p.foo).Count());
```

Comment: Thanx, but two questions: 1) What is the sql result - join? 2) As a result, I get anonymous type. I would like my MVC views to be strongly typed...

Comment: you can inspect your generated sql's with http://code.google.com/p/mvc-mini-profiler/ It has EF code first support, also you can install it via nuget package, check it out.

Comment: It is certainly a join, you can see in intellitrace query,if your strong type if is Foo you  must write p=>new Foo{...}